# DT::datatable only shows code but no output after knitting

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, interactive, dt

This is an Rmd file, and here is the code chunk.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, message=FALSE}
x<-read_lines("HaverfordQual.txt")
text <- x
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "\\|")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c("nothing", "i","school", "think", "know", "none", "really","dont", "never", "someone", "get", "scienc", "like", "friend", "sometim", "realli", "mani", "none", "feel", "idk", "clue")) 
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
wordcloud2(data=d, size=2.0, color='random-dark', shape='rectangle')
```


```{r, include=FALSE}
setwd("/Users/xiaoyujin/Downloads/Haverford 2021-2022 copy")
getwd()
text_df <- read.csv("Haverford21Clean.csv")
```
```{r, echo=FALSE}
text_df %>%
  filter(!is.na(adults) & !adults %in% c("N/A")) %>% 
  mutate(avg_pssm = round(avg_pssm, 2)) %>% 
  select(Grade = grade,
         `Avg. PSSM` = avg_pssm,
         `Race/Ethnicity` = race_eth,
         `Gender` = gender,
         `In what ways can the adults in your school help you feel more connected?` = adults) %>% 
  DT::datatable(rownames = TRUE,
                filter = "top",
                options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                               lengthChange = TRUE,
                               scrollX = FALSE,
                               columnDefs = list(list(width = '50px', targets = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)))))
                                              
```
````

When I run it in the R Studio in the editor section, the table shows up. But when I knit it, only the code shows up in the HTML file and not the output.

I tried to explicitly ask to show both the code and the output (the beginning of the code chunk was ``` {r} ), but it did not work.

Here is the global environment:

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```
````

I thought it should be fine since I want the output of the code but not the code.

Does anyone know why this is the case? What might be the issue?
Thank you so much!

Edit: Appearantly the first chunk might has an issue since deleting it fixes the issue

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, message=FALSE}
x<-read_lines("HaverfordQual.txt")
text <- x
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern ) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "\\|")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, c("nothing", "i","school", "think", "know", "none", "really","dont", "never", "someone", "get", "scienc", "like", "friend", "sometim", "realli", "mani", "none", "feel", "idk", "clue")) 
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
wordcloud2(data=d, size=2.0, color='random-dark', shape='rectangle')
```
````

Comment: Your code is working fine in my case!

Comment: I have the same result as @shafee.  Please provide a minimal *reproducible* example.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help.  Until then, I am voting to close as not reproducible.